# Decompose a 2-peaked pdf into 2 elementary pdfs

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability

How could I decompose a two-peaked (empirical) pdf into 2 say lognormals or other appropriate pdf in a straightforward way? I'd prefer in Matlab.

[image]

to something like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: "Decompose" in which sense?

Comment: Hi Luis, I updated the post. See the pic attached. I  need sthg like that. Thanks!

Comment: So you need the original curve to be the _sum_ of the blue and the red curves, right? But in that case the blue and red curves cannot be pdf's (their integral will be less than 1). I guess you want a linear combination of two pdf's, where the coefficients of the combination add up to 1. Anyway, I can't be of help with that. But I think the question is clearer now

Comment: You might want to consider asking this question in the Cross Validated SE site.

Comment: Thanks Luis. Good points I hadn't thought of.

Comment: Is there a way I can easily move this question to Cross ValidatedSE?

Comment: Have you tried looking at Gaussian Mixture Models?  Assuming your data are normally distributed, you just have to specify how many distributions you're looking for, and GMMs will be able to find those parameters for you for each distribution nicely.  Expectation-Maximization is what is used to find the parameters.  I have code that I written from a long time ago that does this. If you have some data I can try this one, I wouldn't mind giving this a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a mixture density, defined as `p(x) = sum_i a_i p_i(x)`, where `sum_i a_i = 1` and each `p_i(x)` is itself a density function. The most widely-used such model is the Gaussian mixture density, in which each `p_i(x)` is a Gaussian density; I think there are functions to find the parameters for that in some Matlab package. More generally, the `p_i(x)` can be any density. The customary algorithm to fit the parameters is the expectation-maximization algorithm. A web search should turn up a lot of references and probably some Matlab code for that as well.

Comment: Thanks! I found the excellent post http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23611-peak-fitter

Comment: @OliverAmundsen It looks like that code does something a little different. The input is the height of the curve (i.e., the y coordinate); typically for fitting densities you have instead a list of values of the x coordinate. The output of that code is not normalized to integrate to 1. Also, I didn't look at the code but it might or might not handle component densities other than Gaussian densities.

Comment: OK, but was useful anyways to identify the underlying peaks. It also allows Lorentzian curves.